# React: mapping array of objects with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I've sifted through a few questions answered already and learned quite a bit but I am stuck on a formatting issue.

With my components set up currently I am rendering this:

**Half Stack application development**

**Node.js**

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item
4. List item
5. List item

This is what I am attempting to render.

**Half Stack application development**

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item

**Node.js**

4. List item
5. List item

**The data I am mapping**

```
const courses = [
   {
     name: "Half Stack application development",
     id: 1,
     parts: [
       {
         name: "Fundamentals of React",
         exercises: 10,
         id: 1,
       },
       {
         name: "Using props to pass data",
         exercises: 7,
         id: 2,
       },
       {
         name: "State of a component",
         exercises: 14,
         id: 3,
       },
       {
         name: "Redux",
         exercises: 11,
         id: 4,
       },
     ],
   },
   {
     name: "Node.js",
     id: 2,
     parts: [
       {
         name: "Routing",
         exercises: 3,
         id: 1,
       },
       {
         name: "Middlewares",
         exercises: 7,
         id: 2,
       },
     ],
   },
 ];
```

**My components**

```
const Header = ({ course }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {course.map((course) => {
        return <h1>{course.name}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Course = ({ course }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header course={course} />
      <ul>
        {course.map((item) => {
          return item.parts.map((item) => {
            return (
              <li>
                {item.name} {item.exercises}
              </li>
            );
          });
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

my call to the main component

```
 return (
    <div>
      <Course course={courses} />
    </div>
  );
```

Hopefully my problem is obvious that I am not able to figure out how to go to each object in the the array and make the header followed by the parts array names listed below.

Happy to provide more information if needed, I've been stuck on this for three days!

For reference this is from the Full Stack Open 2021 course. Link here https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/rendering_a_collection_modules#exercises-2-1-2-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map through the courses and display the header inside the loop and then loop through the parts

```
courses.map(course => {
 return (
   <div>
   <Header course={course.name}/>   
   {
    course.parts.map(part => display part here)
   }
   </div> 
 )
})
```

Comment: That did it. I just had to go into the header to remove the map function and change the props. I appreciate the help. I understand now that mapping inside the header just creates an array of the titles and tosses them both out.